# Empty Network Places & Can't browse network shares

Tags: windows-xp, networking, network-shares

A friend of mine is having the following issue which I couldn't fix:

1. When going to Network places, it is
   empty, meaning his wireless adapter
   and ethernet adapter are not showing
   up in there.
2. When trying to access a network
   share, either by hostname or ip, it
   can't connect.

I ran a search on google and somebody suggesting running winsock2fix which I did, but it didn't fix anything.

Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you see either of the network adapters in the device manager? Do you see anything in network connections? Do you get link lights when you plug in a cable? Can you see any network names when searching for wireless networks? What is the IP address that you are given when you type ipconfig into the command line? Can you ping your default gateway? I'm really just shooting out a bunch of questions because we really need more information to give you any direction to go with this.

Comment: @MaQleod: yes, i do see them in the device manager. and i do get a valid ip address (internet works fine), and yes, i can ping my default gw.

Comment: ok, can you ping the other computer? either by IP or WINS name? Both directions?

Comment: @MaQleod: yes, pinging the computers by ip or hostname works fine both ways. it does not work though for seeing network shares by using hostname or ip.

Comment: so if you go to the run dialog and type in //hostname/share does it go to the share?

Comment: @MaQleod: no. neither it does by IP. btw, shares use a backslash (\\hostname\share)

Comment: true, on another network, can either computer access shares?